# How to communicate between client side and server side in Node and Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I'm building a web app and i'm using node.js and express.js. I have script.js which is client-side so it communicate with the navigator and i have app.js which is server-side and communicate with the server.

I will simplify my problem:
In script.js I have this variable

```
//script.js
function simple() {
var calcul = 2*2
}
```

I would like to send this var calcul to my server side file : app.js

```
//app.js
let express = require('express');

let app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/assets', express.static('public'))

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.render('index' );
});

//here
var newCalcul = calcul * 2
```

Now i would like to send newCalcul to script.js

```
//script.js
function simple2() {
console.log(newCalcul)
//>8
}
```

So, how to send a variable client-side -> server-side then the opposite send a variable server-side -> client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such Client-Server applications in the web, you can use HTTP. In HTTP, you have different request methods such as GET to read data, POST to send & post data, PUT to update data and DELETE to delete data.

On the client, you do a HTTP POST request to the url with the parameter /abc. In the request body, you provide an object with the data you want to send.

```
const data = { test: "123" };

fetch("https://example.com/abc", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

And to recieve the data from the parameter /abc on the server:

```
app.post('/abc', (req, res) => {
    let data = req.body.test;
    res.send(data);
});
```

With res.send, you send the data back to the client.

Comment: Thanks and how I retrieve data in the client side

Comment: Whenever you make a request, the server will directly respond with a response. This is how the Request-Response-System works. In the example above, the data has been received and logged on the console inside the .then { ( ) } block. I would recommend you to read more about HTTP requests and how they work because this is important when dealing with Client-Server applications.

Comment: Okay I got it, now i'm working in localhost so I put "localhost:8080/abc" instead of "https://example.com/abc" and I got the error : script.js:94 Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/abc. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.

Comment: Okay, i think it should work if you add `http://` in front, like: `http://localhost:8080/abc`

Comment: hmm it's not working I will investigate thanks a lot you deserve your points. Last question : the fetch https://example.com/abc create the page https://example.com/abc and if a user goes to https://example.com/abc he will see the variable right ?

Comment: The fetch does not create the page. The fetch sends data to the endpoint url (`example.com/abc`) which is a POST endpoint. You cannot visit the url on the browser like a webpage, you will get an error. Whenever you visit a website, your browser sends a GET request to receive the page, but with POST, you can only send data. Its tricky to explain, so i think watching a YouTube video or reading something about it will be better :)

Comment: I get it I was using get before and it created a new url which was not what I wanted but the post is perfect thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Great. You’re welcome, i like to help!